# How to get the Push notification received message in the logs

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift4.2

I am getting the push notification to the device. But how to get the message to be printed in the logs? What is the method to be used in order to get the received message to be printed or to be used in any of the code?

For example, We are getting a push notification from Firebase and we need to print in the logs. What is the way to get the message?

Comment: Read the docs please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a delegate method which gets called when a push notification arrives as below:

```
   func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        NSLog(userInfo)
        print(userInfo)
    }
```

The delegate method receives the data in the “userInfo” attribute when a push notification arrives. You can print using print or NSLog(which is available as logs and can be transported any time).